# Making a cube follow my finger in Unity2d?

Tags: unity

I would like to make a cube follow my finger when i touch an iphone screen and drag in unity 2d.

Comment: What have you tried? You should try google... It's the best thing since sliced bread :)

Comment: Check out a library for the Processing language called PeasyCam at http://mrfeinberg.com/peasycam/#about.  Yes, it will not work directly in Unity, but the source is available and it should show you how it works.  Also it will give you a good demo of how this can be done.

Comment: Haven't you already asked practically this exact question? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/73811/how-to-trace-a-line-following-the-users-touch-in-unity3d

Answer (score 1):

The camera class has a method called [`ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3 position)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) pairing that will the [`Input.GetTouch(int index)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) method, you can retrieve the position in the world where the user is touching on the screen. Remember to check the [touch count](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-touchCount.html) before trying to retrieve touch points.

For example, adding a script to the cube with the following in the update method would probably work:

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    this.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
```